# Stop layout rendering for Ajax request with custom routing

Tags: php, ajax, json, zend-framework, layout

How can I stop Layout rendering, when sending request through AJAX..
The problem I face is json data is echoed on the browser, not passed to tha call back function of jquery

here's my script

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/getPrivileges",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(privileges){
        alert('hellooo');

        buildTree(privileges,".privBox h2");
        if($(".privPrivilege"))
            $("#loading").css("visibility","hidden");
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert('Error'+request.responseText);
    }

});
```

and here's the routing

```
resources.router.routes.privilege.route = /getPrivileges
resources.router.routes.privilege.defaults.module = privileges
resources.router.routes.privilege.defaults.controller = privilege
resources.router.routes.privilege.defaults.action = get-privileges
```

and here's my controller

```
  public function getPrivilegesAction() {

        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
         ...........
         ...........
          $this->_helper->json($appPrivArray);
          $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
          $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
          $response = $this->getResponse();
          $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json', true);
   }


 }
```

First I face that layout still rendered but now the json is printed on the screen, even I don't have get-privileges.phtml view page.

and in the init() method of the controller, I make like this

```
 public function init() {
    $ajaxContextSwitch = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContextSwitch->setDefaultContext('json');
    $ajaxContextSwitch->addActionContext('getPrivileges', 'json');
    $ajaxContextSwitch->initContext();
}
```

how can I make response deliver to the call back function of jquery!
It's important to mention that not all urls has custom routes..

please help, because I almost will retire from development using Zend framework !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action, you just need to use

```
$this->_helper->json($appPrivArray)
```

You do not need to use `setNoRender` or anything else.
And in the Javascript you do not need to use `dataType: 'JSON',`
I tested this, should work fine.

Comment: I put all comments on drew010 answer.please check it out.

Comment: If you're still getting the layout, there is one possibility that there is an error in the action and the layout is showing exception message and stack trace instead of returning only json. Have you checked the returned code and seen if there is any exception message in it?

Comment: the problem I was faced is in routing, I have two routes with the same name, so that was the problem..

Comment: Okay. A good idea is to wrap the action controller code in `try ... catch` and return the exception message as json in case of error happens. Like `catch ( Exception $e ) { return $this->_helper->json( array('error' => $e->getMessage()) ) }`

Comment: Mmm, I usually return $e object, thank you for getMessage() info :)

Answer (score 1):

JSON data is returned to jQuery (or any other library) by being "echoed on the browser".  That is how the callback receives the data.

The JSON view helper disables the layout for you, as well as sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` so you shouldn't have to do that.

You can continue to use `setNoRender(true)` if you don't have a view script for the given action.

I think that this code should work fine:

```
public function getPrivilegesAction() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
        $this->_helper->json($appPrivArray);
    }
}
```

Are you receiving any Javascript errors or does the `alert('hello')` not run?

Comment: Now An error occur in js and alert this <!-- application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml -->and the whole html of layout!

Comment: @Salman, I make as you said, now it alert hello, bust still alert the layout script!

Comment: I make alert('hello'+privilege); it alerts the layout page